# External Private API Authentication with Backbone

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, backbone.js, oauth

I am building an API and had questions about handling authentication when using a front-end framework such as Backbone.js.

I have a single API server that is responsible for returning and modifying data based on RESTful web requests.

I have another app server that is a Backbone application. I want this application to connect directly with my API server, so set the entire project up so that this app server can make cross-domain AJAX requests to the API server.

There are some API routes that I do not want unauthorized parties to obtain access to. For example, I have a path /users that lists all the users of my app. I need this path later on for admin functions, but I don't want it publicly available to my app server.

What is a good authentication scheme to use? OAuth won't work because the secret token would be exposed on the front-end. And after that, I'm a little stuck with what my options are. Does anyone have any suggestions moving forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like these I use a combination of techniques.

**-- Good ole Cookie based auth**

As a backbone app will always be used inside a browser and browsers have built-in cookie support, I would suggest that you should accept cookie based sessions on the server side. All the auth related stuff will be handled by the browser and you don't have to worry about storing keys etc. On top many libraries like (NSURL in iPhone) and frameworks (like PhoneGap/Trigger) all support cookies so woha you can support all kind of clients with litte work.

**-- Plain API Key**

For third-parties, I use api-key based authentication. You provide `username` and `password`, I provide key. You send me that key every time in HTTP header for all subsequent requests. I use the key to identify you and then allow/disallow actions accordingly.

I assume once you can authenticate a user (wait..who are you?), then you can setup authorizations ( you say `Micheal` ? ...ok you can access `/users` )

*Also take a look at my [backbone-parse plugin](https://github.com/neebz/backbone-parse) for an idea on how to authenticate users against an external API service #shamelessplug*