# Backbone swtich from Http to Https

Tags: backbone.js, https, routes, http-redirect

I have certain knowledge using Bakcbone.js, and my backend is Restlet Java, but have no idea regarding user authentication

I have built a single-page web app using them, but now the problem arises that, what I am going to do after user login? There are pages that can be viewed by both logged in and not logged in user, and logged in users should be able to see additional content.

By default the page uses http, but after user Login, suppose an Ajax Post, how do I switch entire Backbone App from http to https? And suppose user logs out, how do I switch back?

Are there any convient ways just to switch all my routes in Router, Url/Urlroots in Collection/Model between Http and Https?    (using relative address)

Can I deal with this using Server Redirect..and how can I do that, doesn't that make Http and Https sections completely separated like two apps?

Comment: Why not always serve the page that is hosting the backbone application via HTTPS?

Comment: because some pages can be viewed by both logged in users and not registered users..

Comment: You can use HTTPS for logged in and non-logged in users. Plus, you say it's "one" page? Is it or isn't it? Do you just mean views? Or are there some stand-alone pages from the backbone portion? If Login is part of your Backbone app -- then just serve the whole thing as HTTPS so that users don't need to worry about the safety of their data.

Comment: It is one view. Yes after asking more questions that is actually exactly what I am planning to do, serve everything just under Https would completely solve my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

woha - that's a lot stuff you are thinking ..half of which doesn't even belong to Backbone's scope.

Let's split this up:

`but have no idea regarding user authentication`

[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031363/external-private-api-authentication-with-backbone/15039076#15039076). I just answered this yesterday.

`what I am going to do after user login?`

the normal pattern here is that login is usually one page. If the user successfully logs in then she is redirected to another page which has all the Backbone stuff in it e.g. take a look at a backbone app classdojo.com . Login is simple HTML with no fancy stuff. Once user logs in, she navigates to a single-page app with all heavy client side.

`Are there any convient ways just to switch all my routes in Router, Url/Urlroots in Collection/Model between Http and Https? (using relative address)`

Backbone Router ONLY looks at the route which comes '#' e.g. in `example.com/user#details` Backbone router will only navigate based on `#details` . It has nothing to do with your http protocol.

Your Url/Urlroots can be relative or absolute both. So you can specify full URL with http protocol in them.

Comment: but wouldn't using absolut address cause cross-domain problems? so if I use relative adress, and gets a https redirect, everything will still work exactly fine?

Comment: yup it will. you would be better off if you keep your http page and https separate e.g. login page in http and user dashboard in https.